# Shared cache for Play Framework on heroku

Tags: heroku, memcached, playframework-2.2

I want to have a shared cache for my Play 2.2.2 app hosted on heroku.

I added memcachier addon and in my conf file :

```
memcached=enabled

memcached.host=${MEMCACHE_SERVERS}
memcached.user=${MEMCACHE_USERNAME}
memcached.password=${MEMCACHE_PASSWORD}
```

But the cache is never hit. Is it enought ?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the play plugin : in the **build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc, javaCore, javaJdbc, javaEbean, anorm, filters,
  "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.3",
  "com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached" % "0.3.0.2"
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  "Spy Repository" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2"
)
```

https://github.com/mumoshu/play2-memcached